# Checking which "submit" POST button is pressed with Python's Bottle

Tags: python, html, bottle

Say you have a form with multiple submits:

```
<form method="POST" action="/etc">
    <input name="foo" type="submit" value="Foo!">
    <input name="bar" type="submit" value="Bar!">
</form>
```

Checking which submit button was pressed in PHP is as simple as:

```
if (isset($_POST['foo'])) { return 'foo' }
if (isset($_POST['bar'])) { return 'bar' }
```

What is the Python.Bottle equivalent?

I've tried:

```
if (request.POST.get('foo')):
    return 'foo'
if (request.POST.get('bar')):
    return 'bar'
```

But that returns a KeyError, meaning that 'foo' and 'bar' aren't in the POST dict.

I've also tried adding a test field into the form and returning the value in that field when the form is submitted and that works perfectly, so the form is posting.

One thing that may be important: The submit buttons in the form are dynamically generated.

EDIT: Found a possible problem. I'm using jQuery to post and serializing form data, but apparently jQuery's serialize omits submit buttons from the output, which would definitely cause what I'm seeing. Currently working on a workaround but any help is still appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the browser is including the submit button names in the POST request; use the developer tools included in your browser. There is nothing about a submit button that makes it so special that the server-side can detect it was a submit button and magically omit it, not `bottle` nor any other framework. This is *not* a `bottle`-specific problem.

Comment: Any tips/links to show me how to do that? Using Chrome if possible.

Comment: `View` > `Developer` > `Developer Tools`, choose the `Network` tab, filter on `Documents` (bottom of window), submit your form, select the request made (the `Method` column will show it's a `POST`) and inspect the various tabs shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that jQuery's serialize function ignores submit buttons.

I got around it by adding a class (`submitButton` in the example) to all the relevant submit buttons and adding a hidden input (`theHiddenInput` in the example) to the form, then adding the following handler:

```
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
    this.form.theHiddenInput.value = this.name;
});
```

The following code is the equivalent of my previous code:

```
if (request.POST.get('theHiddenInput') == 'foo'):
    return 'foo'
if (request.POST.get('theHiddenInput') == 'bar'):
    return 'bar'
```

Maybe this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form?

```
<form action="/etc" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="foo" type="submit" value="Foo!">
    <input name="bar" type="submit" value="Bar!">
</form>
```

According to [Bottle Documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf):

> `BaseRequest.forms`
>
> Form values parsed from an `url-encoded` or `multipart/form-data`
>   encoded `POST` or `PUT` request body. The result is retuned as a
>   `FormsDict`. All keys and values are strings. File uploads are stored
>   separately in `files`.

and

> `BaseRequest.POST`
>
> The values of `forms` and `files` combined into a single `FormsDict`.
>   Values are either strings (form values) or instances of
>   `cgi.FieldStorage` (file uploads).

Comment: You can start debugging by printing what has been sent to server. Try to print all keys and values in `request.forms`. Then you can see if jQuery is changing the keys etc.

Comment: for me however it was the solution.
Using pure javascript with bottle.